# Error on the System.log file

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6, system.log

I'm having this below error continuously on the system.log

> [2019-05-07 11:31:30] main.CRITICAL: Item (Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor) with the same ID "1412" already exists. [] []
>   [2019-05-07 11:31:30] main.CRITICAL: Item (Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor) with the same ID "1412" already exists. [] []
>   [2019-05-07 11:31:32] main.CRITICAL: Item (Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor) with the same ID "1412" already exists. [] []
>   [2019-05-07 11:31:33] main.CRITICAL: Item (Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor) with the same ID "1412" already exists. [] []
>   [2019-05-07 11:31:35] main.CRITICAL: Item (Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor) with the same ID "1412" already exists. [] []
>   [2019-05-07 11:31:37] main.CRITICAL: Item (Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor) with the same ID "1412" already exists. [] []
>   [2019-05-07 11:31:39] main.CRITICAL: Item (Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor) with the same ID "1412" already exists. [] []
>   [2019-05-07 11:31:41] main.CRITICAL: Item (Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor) with the same ID "1412" already exists. [] []
>   [2019-05-07 11:31:42] main.CRITICAL: Item (Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor) with the same ID "1412" already exists. [] []
>   [2019-05-07 11:31:43] main.CRITICAL: Item (Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor) with the same ID "1412" already exists. [] []
>   [2019-05-07 11:31:44] main.CRITICAL: Item (Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor) with the same ID "1412" already exists. [] []
>   [2019-05-07 11:31:46] main.CRITICAL: Item (Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor) with the same ID "1412" already exists. [] []
>   [2019-05-07 11:31:47] main.CRITICAL: Item (Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor) with the same ID "1412" already exists. [] []
>   [2019-05-07 11:31:48] main.CRITICAL: Item (Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor) with the same ID "1412" already exists. [] []
>   [2019-05-07 11:31:49] main.CRITICAL: Item (Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor) with the same ID "1412" already exists. [] []
>   [2019-05-07 11:31:49] main.CRITICAL: Item (Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor) with the same ID "1412" already exists. [] []
>   [2019-05-07 11:31:52] main.CRITICAL: Item (Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor) with the same ID "1412" already exists. [] []
>   [2019-05-07 11:31:53] main.CRITICAL: Item (Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor) with the same ID "1412" already exists. [] []
>   [2019-05-07 11:31:55] main.CRITICAL: Item (Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor) with the same ID "1412" already exists. [] []
>   [2019-05-07 11:31:56] main.INFO: Reference to undeclared plugin with name 'products_grid_collection'. [] []

If i delete that category ID. The same error is coming with another category ID.

Please Anyone help me to clear this issue.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Delete records from **url_rewrite** table where "entity_type" is "category_id".
> 2. run `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Comment: Can i truncate the whole url_rewrite table? Please explain me clearly

Comment: DELETE FROM `url_rewrite` WHERE `entity_id` = "category_id";

Comment: Hi, i had deleted and run the reindex command. But that same error coming again with another id :(